# Wrapping non-static classes in a static container

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a lot of manager classes which I use to access the database. I need to create an instance of a manager in order to access its methods.

Since I personally prefer static classes for this, I would like to know what you think of this approach:

```
public static class Managers
{
    public static SomeManager Manager
    {
         get { return new SomeManager(); }
    }
}

var stuff = Managers.SomeManager.DoStuff();
```

Any downsides?

Comment: other than the obvious one of creating a new object every time?

Comment: I'd rather use some DI container like Unity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest downside to this is the lack of clarity to someone unfamiliar with your code: to me, a call like this

```
Managers.SomeManager.DoStuff();
```

means accessing `SomeManager` that is fixed in one way or the other, as opposed to

```
new SomeManager().DoStuff();
```

which tells me explicitly that `SomeManager` is being created on demand.

Converting `SomeManager` property into a method with an appropriate name, say, `MakeSomeManager()`, would restore readability:

```
Managers.MakeSomeManager().DoStuff();
```

You may want to do something like this in order to hide the process of instantiating `SomeManager`, the constructor of which may require some parameters that you are unwilling to carry around.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad implementation of the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), as you are creating a new instance every time the property is called.

This would be better:

```
public static class Managers
{
    private static SomeManager someManagerInstance;

    public static SomeManager Manager
    {
         get
         {
             if (someManagerInstance == null)
             {
                 someManagerInstance = new SomeManager();
             }
             return someManagerInstance;
         }
    }
}
```

Unless of course, that having a new instance every time is desired? In which case, I would wrap the creation in a method, rather than a property:

```
public static class Managers
{
    public static SomeManager GetNewManager()
    {
         return new SomeManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: readonly is even better, (don't need to check if null)

Comment: @Sayse That would mean eager initialization. I prefer the lazy way.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Singleton pattern. And if you're on .NET 4 or greater, the neatest (and 'laziest' version) is:

```
public sealed class SomeManager
{
    private static readonly Lazy<SomeManager> lazy = 
        new Lazy<SomeManager>(() => new SomeManager());

    public static SomeManager Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private SomeManager()
    {
    }
}
```

Then access it via:

```
var stuff = SomeManager.Instance.DoStuff();
```

Implementing a thread-safe singleton has lots of pitfalls so you should check [this](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) out for some tips and examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton instead, because using of static classes and methods like this is bad practice. For example try to write some unit tests for your implementation or else...

1) Create singleton class like this

```
    public static class Singleton<T>
    where T : class, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The syncRoot.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// The instance.
    /// </summary>
    private static volatile T instance;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new T();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Create your class like this

```
public class YourClass
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Singleton instance of 
    /// </summary>
    public static YourClass Instance
    {
        get { return Singleton<YourClass>.Instance; }
    }
...methods etc...
}
```

3) Call your singleton from code
    YourClass.Instance.SomeMethodCall();